# Why the structure of mongoose subdocument can be different?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Is it expected behaviour of mongoose, or it shouldn't be like this. So I have 2 schema for users and address. The schema looks like these:

```js
const addressSchema = {
  addressLine: { type: String},
  city: { type: String},
  locations: { type: String, coordinates: [Number] }, <-- subdocument
}

const userSchema = {
  name: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  addresses: {
    primary: { type: AddressSchema },
    others: { type: [AddressSchema] }
  }
}
```

And I try to insert this data:

```js
{
   name: "John Doe",
   addresses: {
     primary: {
       addressLine: "Apple Street"
     },
     others: [
       {
         addressLine: "Mango Street"
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

Now this is the confusing part. So I didn't include the `locations` in the input. But the data that saved in my DB looks like this:

```js
{
  name: "john Doe",
  addresses: {
    primary: {
      addressLine: "Apple Street"
    },
    others: [
      {
         addressLine: "Mango Street",
         locations: {       <-- this locations suddenly shown!
           coordinates: []
         }
      }
    ]
  }
  _id: randomString,
  __v: 0
}
```

Please help, and thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `locations` is automatically added in your subdocument because of `coordinates` field in it.

Whenever you define an array `enter code here`type field in your schema, Mongoose automatically initialises it with empty array if the value is not provided.

And,since you are not passing any value to `locations.coordinates`, it is initializing it as an empty array.

If you want to test this theory, please remove `coordinates` from `locations`, and you will see the difference.

Comment: but `locations` not showing in `primary` property. Only showing in `others`